# Does Entity Framework make one database call per operation?

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to profile EF to understand more of its inner workings, I have tried to add two entities using the `Add` method and the `AddRange` method, then of course committing with the `SaveChanges` method. And here is what I got on the profiler in both cases.

[image]

Does this mean that EF actually makes two trips to the database one per insert? which means that if I am trying to insert 100 entities for example this will mean 100 trips to the database? which will greatly impact performance. or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes that's right.  The alternative is to use bulk insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, it will issue one database call per item attempting to be added, as it is using the standard SQL `INSERT` command in this case.

The alternatives would be to use `BULKINSERT`, such as using a stored procedure that takes in an object such as a `DataTable`.

Comment: It would also be theoretically possible for it to use a pattern when it inserts from a select [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601906/perform-insert-with-select-to-insert-multiple-records), but parameterization get tricky in that case.  I suspect that is why this pattern isn't used.

Comment: But this is a very non smart way to deal with the database, it could get really ugly for big systems as in my case, are there any performance issues with EF6 that I should look into?

Comment: EF was never designed to handle bulk operations.  It was meant to handle  a small number of object-graph based operations at a time.  There have been some [3rd party extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/?z=codeplex) added that can handle it though.